# C# shared property & field inheritance

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, inheritance

I've been trying to perfectly structure this project I'm working on in different classes while maximizing the benefits of inheritance. So far however, it's given me more headaches than benefits.

Consider this:

```
public class SuperClass : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] protected Camera _camera;
}
```

and this

```
public class SubClass : SuperClass
{

}
```

- Both scripts are attached to different game objects in the scene.
- The Camera is to be assigned by dragging it in the inspector

I tried this, and unity seemed to tell me that I had to assign the camera to the SuperClass game object AND to the subclass game object, which makes no sense to me.

**How can I assign a camera to SuperClass.cs, which is then used and shared by all of its subclasses?**

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Modify the `protected` to `public`

Comment: Are these two different instances, or only one? If it's the same instance AND you are able successfully to assign the camera to the object as a SuperClass, it should work as expected. If they are different instances, inheritance won't help you-- each instance will need its own assignment. There is a way around this (with a `static` member, perhaps assigned by an instance property) but that's a slightly different solution.

Comment: @DominicP I've tried all sorts of things, static fields being one of them.
The problem with those static fields for me is, that they don't appear in the inspector. And I don't really want to get into writing my own custom editor just for this.

Comment: You could use a combination of a static field and a non-static property. `static Camera camera;` followed by `public /* non-static */ Camera Camera { get { return camera; /* return the shared, static instance */ } set { camera = value; /* set the static instance */ } }`

Comment: @DominicP I've tried that aswell, and 'Camera' doesn't show up in my unity inspector.

Comment: Huh. Maybe you should overthink your code structure, however, I would pass a `SuperClass` object as an argument instead of inheriting it, this would save you a lot of initialization...

Comment: @Essigwurst Could you give an example of passing it as an argument? I know what they are and how they're used, but I want to make sure we're thinking about the same usage here.

Comment: what you are trying to do is bad practice!  first please take a look at: "favour composition over inheritance pattern"

next thing is you should Use a ServiceLocator pattern OR using DI/IoC (e.g. with Zenject). 

With your solution you have to set the camera to every Gameobject or you have to expose an static Field/Property and have a lot of smelly Code within your Superclass.

Answer (score 1):

> shared by all of its subclasses

Shared by classes could can only be achieved by using "static" (static variable or singleton).

A workaround could be

```
public class SubClass :SuperClass 
{
     [SerializeField] Camera camera;

     void Awake()
     {
         if(camera!=null)
         {
             _camera=camera;
         }
     }

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        camera=_camera;
    }
}
```

To further extend the solution, you could write a editor script or just get the camera from the code.

Comment: I've tried the singleton pattern as a solution for my problem before, and I had the best results creating singletons which inherit from a generic singleton class.
I didn't end up using it though, because in my case, SubClass already inherits from another class, so I couldn't make it also inherit from the generic singleton class. In your example, how would creating the camera in one of the SubClasses make it shared by all subclasses? I'm gonna guess it's a typo, but I want to ask first.

Comment: @Thrindil Just drag the camera to one instance of subclass. After hit the play button, all the instances of subclass will automatically shared it.(check inspector).

Comment: Unfortunately, that doesn't work either.
When I drag the camera to one instance of subclass, it does get assigned to that instance, but not automatically to the other instances of subclass.
I think I'll have to learn how to work with scripteable objects to get a proper, fleshed out solution for this problem.

Comment: @Thrindil Did u hit the run button? It assign the camera to all instances at runtime. If you want to do it in compile time, then u should dig into editor scripts. Nevertheless, I think get camera from the code is the easy way to do it. Alternatively, if you decide do it in runtime, u can get camera use GameObject find or sth simliar.

Comment: I editted my code, waited for unity to refresh, dragged the camera to an instance of SubClass, hit the play button, and noticed that only that one instance of SubClass had the camera assigned. The rest had "none" in their camera field in the inspector. Maybe it's because SuperClass also has an instance of itself in my scene, but I don't think that should be a problem.

Comment: @Thrindil did u mark your camera in your superclass as static? If not, change it to static.

Comment: I didn't, and it worked once I did. Thanks.
While it works, this is not exactly what I was looking for though.
My question was this: How can I assign a camera to SuperClass, which is then used and shared by all of its subclasses?
And now I'm doing kind of the opposite:
I'm assigning a camera to one instance of SubClass and share this camera with an instance of SuperClass. It feels wrong, and since I have multiple SubClasses of SuperClass, which should all have equal privileges, it doesn't make sense from a design perspective to assign a camera to an instance of one of those subclasses.

Comment: @Thrindil If your superclass is one instance in scene, then if you drag it to the superclass. It should work as well. Actually I am missing the context here what exactly you want to achieve in a broader view.  In another word, why you want to achieve this?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/186794/discussion-between-alexwei-and-thrindil).

Answer (score 0):

You need to create public static Camera property somewhere and reference it in your code, using property:

```
public static class StaticValues
{
    public static Camera Camera {get; set;} 
}
public class SuperClass : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] protected Camera _camera
    {
        get
        {
            return StaticValues.Camera;
        }
        set
        {
            StaticValues.Camera = value;
        }
    }
}
public class SubClass : SuperClass
{

}
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with some of the code you used, so I'm interested.
First of all though, I'd like to say that my IDE tells me that [serializefield] can only be applied on fields and not on properties, so it won't show up in the inspector.
As far as I know, the property also won't show up in the inspector if it's made public from the start.

Could you elaborate the rest of the code a little?
I've never used that inherit type of thing ( : base ) on a method before.
What's happening there?
And are you making use of the constructors somehow?
I didn't think they were used in monobehaviour..

Comment: I haven't touched monobehaviour constructors since I got that warning message telling me that monobehaviours shouldn't be instantiated with the keyword 'new'.
But maybe I'm wrong in thinking that monobehaviours don't use constructors because of this.

Comment: Ok, it’s not a big problem, you can use field if you want, there are no differences here. Alse this construction with : base is called “c# constructor inheritance“, it means that when you create an instance of class “SubClass”, which has field _camera, you just call constructor of your base class there (SuperClass), passing there that very Camera object.

Comment: I've applied your code above to my code, and I get a nullreference on the camera.
To verify, I put a Debug.Log() statement in the constructor of SuperClass, and it didn't get printed, so the Constructor doesn't get called. Coming from a non-monobehaviour environment and java, this is confusing to me, and I think that's why I avoided constructors in monobehaviour in the past.
Does it somehow work for you, and am I missing something?

Comment: Just did some more research, and as I thought, you read everywhere on the internet that constructors should NEVER be called in a monobehaviour script.

Comment: Ok, maybe now I understand, what you really want, is just to allow all instances of your superclass and subclass to have one value of _camera (seems to me, AlexWei answer is  more correct here), please check my edited answer.

Comment: Your understanding is correct, I do want all my instances of subclass to have a single value of _camera. I tried out your solution, and I concluded that declaring a 'static' variable in monobehaviou' is a huge part of my problem.
If you think about it, a static variable is the way to go.
But as soon as I declare a field static, it's not visible anymore in the unity inspector, and thus I cannot assign the value of the field..

Comment: I am not acquainted with unity inspector, but can suggest that you should try 
1. use static property instead of static field: public static Camera camera {get; set;}
2. your superclass and subclass don't have static fiields/properties, so you can try to create some library, based on code above, maybe unity will accept it
3. You can try to use .net Environment variables instead of static fields/properies:
Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable(), Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable()
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.environment.setenvironmentvariable?view=netframework-4.7.2

Comment: I've pretty much tried everything except for writing a custom editor script, but I'm thinking about using scriptable objects as data containers instead.